# Android constraint layout cuts off the text in textview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

My xml file is using constraint layout the text does not gets wrapped properly, using the dependency `'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="254dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail_image_view"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

    <TextView
        tools:text="name of the movie"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/original_title"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/thumbnail_image_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/thumbnail_image_view" />

    <TextView
        tools:text="ReleaseDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/release_date"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/original_title"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/original_title" />

    <TextView
        tools:text="Ratings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/user_rating"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/release_date"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/release_date" />

    <Button
        tools:text="Favourite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fav_btn"
        android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:onClick="addToFav"/>

    <TextView
        tools:text="ConstraintLayout allows you to create large and complex layouts with a flat view hierarchy (no nested view groups). It's similar to RelativeLayout in that all views are layed out according to relationships between sibling views and the parent layout, but it's more flexible than RelativeLayout and easier to use with Android Studio's Layout Editor.
        Everything you can do with ConstraintLayout is available directly from the Layout Editor's visual tools, because the layout API and the Layout Editor were specially built for each other. So you can build your layout with ConstraintLayout entirely by drag-and-dropping instead of editing the XML."
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/synopsis"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/fav_btn"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/user_rating"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/user_rating"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The design view looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set padding in each component of your layout for example:

```
 <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/plus" />
```

Try this.

Comment: Welcome @OutOfBounds94

Answer (score 1):

The answer is wrong. You should set constrain for the textView instead of using "wrap_content"